# Need email to have attachments in them in the replys from recipients

Tags: microsoft-outlook

how can I force recipients of my emails with attachments, to reply with the attachment when they reply. I'm using Outlook 2013.

Comment: Simply put, you can't force someone send you an attachment no matter what email program you use.

Comment: http://www.msoutlook.info/question/564

Answer (score 1):

These are not foolproof so you will sometimes have to re-add the attachments after you get a reply.

Method 1

Create a template with Reply and ReplyAll actions disabled. The responders are forced to use Forward. You will probably find only the original mail is affected.

[Prevent e-mail message recipients from using Reply All or Forward](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Prevent-e-mail-message-recipients-from-using-Reply-All-or-Forward-edaa237e-629f-489c-8fa2-cb65dd489225?CorrelationId=7162f6aa-470c-4314-8a6b-e2cb8b2fa97c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

"This feature requires both the sender and recipient to be using Microsoft Outlook."

Method 2

Disable actions with VBA. You can use this on any mail not just the first.

[How To Easily Disable ReplyToAll And Forward In Outlook](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToEasilyDisableReplyToAllAndForwardInOutlook.aspx)

"To be clear. This technique does NOT send macros in your email. It only flips a metadata bit in the message and that metadata is only transmitted within Exchange (within your company). It is not propagated to outside email addresses."

```
Sub NoReply_NoReplyAll()
    ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Reply").Enabled = False
    ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False
End Sub
```